# How to force VS 2010 to break when corrupting the heap in debug?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, heap-corruption

according to MSDN, Visual Studio uses a special heap in debug mode that has extra "no man's land" bytes set to 0xFD by default to track heap corruption
Is there a way to force visual to break when such values are overwritten? I can't find this information anywhere and it seems extremely useful, much more than having to manually dump the memstat like MSDN proposes

thanks

Comment: Ok I managed to fix some heap corruption problems, but I still have some heap corruption during the "return EXIT_SUCCESS;" line of my program, even thought I do a _ASSERTE( _CrtCheckMemory() ); just before the return. What kind of heap corruption/problem could cause this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using `_CrtSetDbgFlag()` when in debug mode.

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5at7yxcs%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: thanks a lot, it is what I was looking for. Now that I fixed some heap corruption problems, I still have some heap corruption during the "return EXIT_SUCCESS;" line of my program, even thought I do a _ASSERTE( _CrtCheckMemory() ); just before

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pause execution the next time a place in memory is changed then set a [data breakpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/350dyxd0.aspx). You need to know in advance where the corruption will occur. You maybe need to set a regular break point where a memory is allocated and where no man's land is set to 0xFD. After that point you have a location in memory, and just set the data breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [AppVerifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms220948%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) with your application?